# Can i test in-app purchases when the status is "Waiting for Review"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I created several "in-App Purchases" and submitted them, thinking it would work just as well for testing. However, they do not appear in the application (SKProductsResponse). Can you test the products with the appropriate test users, once they are marked as "Waiting for Review"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help but i ended up deleting the folder "xcuserdata" and the file "project.xcworkspace" from within "MyProjectName.xcodeproj". Deleting also the files from "DerivedData" and resetting the simulator. Only this worked for me.

Comment: Ah cool :) Well anything that works! Sometimes it will act up unless you clean your project or delete cached data :) Can be a pain to debug indeed ;)

Comment: Thanks! Have removed the app from simulator and relaunched X-Code and simulator. No more invalid product Ids :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I know you should easily be able to test your in-app purchasing without even submitting your binary, I have done this several times for projects in the company I am working in. Submitting the binary should not be a requirement.

The most common problem I've had when getting empty product responses is that the project is not using the proper bundle identifier, so make sure it is set correctly in xCode. You should also be signing with the proper provisioning profile.

This also counts if you are sending your application out to test users (if this is the situation you are in), as far as I know.